# Full Text Search On Relational Tables?

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

I have an sql server database that has multiple tables that are all related to each other.

I am wondering is it possible to use FreeTextTable or ContainsTable for this?

I have only seen examples of looking at one table and search all the columns. I have not seen a case where I may have say a form. Lets call it "student application form".

On this form it may have information like

- Student First Name
- Student Last Name
- Address
- Campus they wish to study at
- Tell us about yourself

Now I want to build 1 search box that will search all these tables and find this "application"

the user might type in

John Smith
Main Campus
motivated

So all tables and columns would need to be checked, but end result would be brining back the application(s) that the full text search thinks matches what was typed in.

The table structure might be like this

Application

- id
- firstName
- lastName
- campusId
- AddressId

Campus

- id
- name

Address

- id
  -Name

In my real database I got like 5 or 6 tables that join with the "application" table and would all need to be accounted for.

Can this be done with full text search? Or do I have to search each table individually and somehow tie it all together again.

Comment: No. Both those functions only accept one table: *"table Is the name of the table that has been marked for full-text querying. table or viewcan be a one-, two-, or three-part database object name. When querying a view, only one full-text indexed base table can be involved."* Possibly you could `UNION ALL` the results, or perhaps use some kind of `LEFT JOIN`. Hard to say without seeing your existing query, and table schema

Answer (score 0):

You can use an indexed view that concatenante all values that you want to search for...

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.V_FT
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
SELECT A.id, 
       CONCAT(firstName, '#', lastName, '#', C.name, '#',D.name) AS DATA
FROM   dbo.Application
       JOIN dbo.Campus AS C ON C.id = A.campusId
       JOIN dbo.Address AS D ON C.id = A.AddressId;
GO

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX X_V_APP ON dbo.V_FT (id);
GO
```

Then create an FT index on DATA colums of the indexed view

Comment: Can't I keep them all as separate columns in the view or do I need join them all into one column?

Comment: Yes you can have the three columns